What computer and display technologies are most reliable and maintainable in a rugged space future?
It’s the distant future; humanity is scattered among the stars, far-flung, sparsely populated. It’s frontier living. Individuals and communities are often cut off from major industrial centers; access to advanced production is limited, and people often have to fend for themselves, get scrappy, get creative. Technology can’t get too advanced, because regular people need to keep it running with the tools they have. “Farmer ingenuity”, as my boss calls it. You slap something together that’ll work for now, and figure out ways to make a machine with a 10 year lifespan last 20.
This kind of setup is sort of implicit in crunchy, 70’s-80’s retrofuture technological aesthetics like you’d find in Star Wars or Alien. CRTs, lots of physical buttons and switches, scan lines, bad audio, the works.
But realistically, what computer and display technologies are actually maintainable long-term in a setting like this? You’re a farmer on an alien planet, or a trained-on-the-job technician on a rustbucket spaceship. Your computers and screens and other “modern” equivalent technologies have been designed by people who know their machines are going to work hard, last long, and be replaced with what’s commonly on hand.
What does low-high-tech look like in this universe? What modern day computer and display technologies are lowest-common-denominator rugged and repairable? Are CRTs actually feasible long-term? What does circuitry look like when your microchips realistically can’t get that micro? Is magnetic tape actually a good idea?

What technologies are the most suitable depends on what technology is available, and the question does not even come close to describing the actual technological and economic environment. On the other hand, the question assumes that some sort of interstellar transport is available, even if it is a "rustbucket spaceship". It is hard to write coherently about a world in which interstellar ships exist and can be maintained in operation but LCD screens are somehow too complicated.

Most movies and TV shows make no substantial effort to invent a "future" technology that would in any way meet the expectations of the [tag:science-based] tag. More often than not, they use the technology of the day and declare any conditions due to narrative necessity to be so. Considering that 99.99% of all human innovation occurred in the last 150 years and that the tech 20 years ago isn't worth much today, what expectations do you have? Other than to make your story appear old and tired?

Oh, and no, CRTs aren't feasible for the long term - which is why you don't see them in anyone's living rooms anymore. I'm an electrical engineer and I'm not even sure where to start. You want "realistic" but you're missing all of my high school and college education and 30+ years of experience. We couldn't even talk the same language. The scope of your question is massive. Can we simplify it? Yup. Your future will be modular. People don't repair "circuits," they replace modules. My industry lives and breathes abstraction - and you'll need to as well.

Please carefully read the [tour], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and [ask] to better understand the limits of Stack Exchange and this Stack. Please consider using the Sandbox to better understand how to ask questions. Thanks.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I think you've got the core of a good question here. Rather than asking for a list of specific technologies, you might want to consider rephrasing this in terms of components. You're on the right track with farmer engineering! Think WD40 vs duct tape and how you might have to splice a couple lawn mower engines together to get your tractor running. JBH has offered some great tips for you to get this question into shape!

Any realistic spacefaring civilization would be extremely motivated to quickly develop and advance the technology, even more so when know-how is available. If they can't/won't do it, it needs to be explained (like why computers are banned in Dune).

I think the question might be answerable if approached from “what’s the most rugged, self-maintainable computer tech available today for someone who is going to be extremely cut off from repairs/support indefinitely?”

@SRM Except that it's not that simple at all. There's a big difference between what you do to make the case of a computer rugged and what you do to make the integrated circuits or printed circuit boards rugged. Worse, I'm not sure "rugged" is the right word. The more I think about this, the more this is a story-based question: do we take (a) the everythings-so-complex-we-need-an-engineering-department (Star Trek) path or (b) the everythings-so-modularized-my-little-sister-could-do-it (Firefly/Serenity) path? It feels like the OP is asking for an aesthetic.

@JBH Definitely on the edge of our ability to answer, which was why I was brainstorming ways to meaningfully answer.

I have a note to consider regarding the expected durability of components, independent of the used technology. Expect the industry to adopt to make more durable components than we have today. Today on earth it is the cheapest approach to use cheap components, which you can easily get within a few days. If you have a big target group where a delivery takes month or more, then you want to save money on the delivery instead of on the cheap production. Expect to get more durable and easier repairable stuff which is more expensive to buy. Similar as we had 40-50 years ago.

I'd frame-challenge this. If you're an extremely isolated colony, your number one goal  is explosive population growth. It's a matter of vital self-preservation to avoid collapsing into the stone age. So what you really want is the highest-tech stuff that you can make locally out of local materials, using a self-replicating local infrastructure that you built out of non-self-replicating ultra-high-tech stuff that you brought with you. It doesn't matter how long your iPhone lasts if you have to share it with all 300 of your great-grandchildren.


access to advanced production is limited

That is the key. Limited is not the same as not available at all.
The key is integrated circuits. New semiconductor fabrication plants are billion dollar (sometimes multi-billion) facilities. And the supply chain is pretty big too. Your far-flung planet with a million settlers just isn't going to build a modern chip factory. But as long as you have limited access to that advanced production, things are going to be OK.
A lot of parts are easier to make - resistors, capacitors, cables, etc. A periodic shipment of chips will take care of the really hard-to-make stuff. Another key is that a lot of today's chips are multifunction - the same microprocessor can run a traffic signal or a home or office computer. And an FPGA can replace almost anything up to a certain level of complexity.
The other key is that modern electronics are very rugged. They won't last forever, but a typical LCD screen can handle a lot more abuse than a typical CRT and a typical SSD can handle a lot more abuse than a typical spinning hard drive.
And finally, keep in mind that you don't need Ghz CPU speeds and Gigabytes of RAM and Terabytes of storage to get real work done. Mhz CPUs with Megabytes of RAM (often Kilobytes of RAM) and Megabytes of storage can run just about anything you really need to do, as long as need isn't defined as "instant access to cat videos".

Nothing, or trading spare parts
To quote John F Kennedy: "We choose to go to the Moon in this decade and do the other things, not because they are easy, but because they are hard"
Space is hard. Impossibly hard. Staying with a small group planet bound won't help you much either though. You'll lack the manpower and collective know how to set up the complex chains required for producing basically any modern equivalent. It isn't always about manpowerm you could maybe start mining, refining and casting iron. You will miss people working on thatbon other tasks though. Even if it's 'part time'. If you go out into small frontiers, your technology level sinks to an abyssal low.
Except it doesn't have to be. All you need is some semi-regular trading. Your outposts are visited once in a while by some merchants that either require something from the outpost, or are subsidised to supply the outposts for cheap/free. The kicker is that you can have a range of how scrappy your people are. You can go from the 'we can barely scrounge a wooden bucket to transport water' to your technician detatching the old palm sized supercomputer and replacing it with a new one. Because to be fair, maintaining a CRT or a microled display will go about the same if all you have to repair it is a wrench. You'll quickly need advanced tools, or simply trade the good stuff from traders. How else to get a CRT in the first place?
